# How to implement bar navigation in react native with customized buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

[image]

Hello, I am new to React native and would like to get a help with this situation.
How can I create this kind of navigation ?

It's not a duplicate of [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060190/how-to-implement-tab-navigation-in-react-native)

I don't want to use `CreateBottomTabNavigator`, because as you can see, navigation bars are at the top.

Comment: You can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator

Comment: I am trying it out right now and can't customize border width.It takes full length of the tab, but as you can notice from the screen, I need it to be approximately 80%.

Comment: You can change that using the indicator style, let me try it out and post an answer

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks a lot for taking you time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a custom tabbar to implement this.

You can see the code for the custom tab bar here

```
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation, position }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Animated.Text
              style={{
                color: isFocused ? 'white' : 'grey',
                marginVertical: 10,
              }}>
              {label}
            </Animated.Text>
            <View
              style={{
                width: '80%',
                backgroundColor: isFocused ? 'white' : 'transparent',
                height: 5,
                marginTop: 'auto',
              }}></View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

And you will have to use it in your Navigator like below

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
```

Output will be

[image]

You can try out the snack for this
https://snack.expo.io/am8bsZI-4

You can change the colors, height and margins as per you need.

Other options are to use the renderIndicator or the indicatorStyle but those wont take the width properly so the above would be the best option.